# Upon clicking save, how do I stop the node from inserting?

Tags: 7, nodes

Upon saving a new node, I need to check against a function, if its field value is available. If not, I need to prevent the node from saving.

```
function mymodule_node_insert($node) {
    $uniqueName = $node->field_name['und'][0['value'];
    if (checkIfAvailable($uniqueName) == FALSE) { die; }
}

function checkIfAvailable($uniqueName) {
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be in code, or could you utilise Rules?

Comment: Code, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably just use [Unique field](http://drupal.org/project/unique_field), as all of the legwork is done.

> This module performs additional validation when a node is created or
> updated by a user to require that a node's title, author, language,
> and CCK fields are unique within a given context.

If you really want it in code though, I'd take a look through the [source](http://drupalcode.org/project/unique_field.git/tree/refs/heads/7.x-1.x) of this module and see how it adds the extra validation.

I know you said you'd prefer it in code, but I've left this here just in case it benefits anyone with the same question as you :-)

Comment: Thanks. But just a note, I am not looking to provide a unique field, but rather to check the field against a function. It's actually checking if the subdomain exists.

Comment: @timofey Aaah..ok...sorry for wasting your time :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should actually be using [`hook_node_validate()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7) as opposed to `hook_node_insert()`

> Perform node validation before a node is created or updated.

Then to prevent it saving you can implement [`form_set_error`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7)

You'll want to check the node type first, so your code would look *something* like the following.

```
function MYMODULE_node_validate(&$node, $form, $form_state) {
  if ($node->type == 'MYNODETYPE') {
    $valuetocheck = $node->field_name[$node->language][0]['value'];
    $available = MYMODULE_checkifavailable($valuetocheck);

    if (!$available) {
      $errormessage = t('Sorry, this field has failed validation');
      form_set_error($node->field_name, $errormessage);
    }
  }
}

function MYMODULE_checkifavailable($valuetocheck) {
  //Do all your checking and return true or false
}
```

Note that I've "namespaced" your custom function here - it's up to you whether or not you do this, but it's good practice to do so :-)

Please also excuse my blatant exploitation of variables here, it's mainly so it's easier to read on this site - but it is also [good practice](http://drupal.org/coding-standards#array) to keep line lengths below 80 characters. I think this comes form the old character based terminal days only being able to show 80 characters/24 lines - knowledge is power ;-).

Comment: Awesome! I'll check it out tomorrow and report :)